# Ionic FabButton not properly working on iPhone

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, floating-action-button

I'm using Ionic FabButton for a floating button over the content in a fixed position. My code is:-

```
<ion-fab bottom right class="fab-image" (tap)="nextStep()">
   <button ion-fab style="display: none;"></button>
   <img src="assets/icon/custom/green_arrow.png" alt="">
</ion-fab>
```

My CSS fir this `fab-image` is as follows:-

```
.fab-image{
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 62px;
}
```

Now it's working on Android just fine:-

[Click here to see how it's working on Android](https://youtu.be/csrgWZ90AkU)

And in iPhone it's working like this:

[Click here to see how it working on iPhone](https://youtu.be/XwDzOTal8lY)

The problem is the glitch on iPhone. The fab button moves as the screen moves. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: It was a known issue https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7624  I have this problem in my project as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem on IOS, the fab wasn't fixed, here's my code.

```
<ion-content>
    <!--other code-->

    <ion-fab class="centered-fab" bottom>
         <button  ion-button block round color="primary" (click)="onClick()">
          Click Me
         </button>
    </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

The issue is gone after I move  outside of

```
<ion-content>
    <!--other code-->
</ion-content>

<ion-fab class="centered-fab" bottom>
     <button  ion-button block round color="primary" (click)="onClick()">
      Click Me
     </button>
</ion-fab>
```

[image]

Comment: It's totally solved my problem too. Any idea why? Thanks for the reply. I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: No, I don't know exactly why...  spent a couple of hours searching on Ionic github issues and forum and finally figured it out